# How regex get last element's time between a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

e.g
I'd like to get below sentence last agree time like pic.

input :

```
Agree|AAA Agree 7/28 22:34,Agree|BBBB Agree 7/28 23:20,Agree|CCC Agree 7/29 07:41,Agree|JJJ Agree 7/29 07:45,Agree|DDD Agree 7/29 07:54,forward|EEE forward 7/29 07:54,forward|FFF forward 7/29 07:54,forward|GGG forward 7/29 07:54,forward|HHHH forward 7/29 07:54
```

expected output :

```
7/29 07:54
```

[image: image-20200729082045279]

I've tried to use LINQ but i can only do it like the picture.

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "Agree|AAA Agree 7/28 22:34,Agree|BBBB Agree 7/28 23:20,Agree|CCC Agree 7/29 07:41,Agree|JJJ Agree 7/29 07:45,Agree|DDD Agree 7/29 07:54,forward|EEE forward 7/29 07:54,forward|FFF forward 7/29 07:54,forward|GGG forward 7/29 07:54,forward|HHHH forward 7/29 07:54";
    var output = input.Split('|')
        .Where(_ => _.Contains("Agree")).Select((e, index) => new {e,index})
        .OrderByDescending(_=>_.index)
        .Take(1);
}
```

[image: image-20200729082008606]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex would do the trick

```
Agree (\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(?!.*Agree \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})
```

This means `Agree \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}` not followed by any occurence of `Agree \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}`

Then you would do this to extract `7/29 07:54` into `lastAgree` variable

```
string pattern = @"Agree (\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(?!.*Agree \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})";           

// Get your match using pattern
var match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);

// Groups[1] is (\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})
var lastAgree = match.Groups[1].Value;
```